# What would be steps to install appcelerator studio with older version titanium sdk & other components?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

What would be steps to install appcelerator studio with older version titanium sdk & other components ? I need steps.

Answer (score 0):

In Appcelerator do this:

1. Open "Help"
2. Click "Install Axway Appcelerator SDK..."
3. Select "Install from update stream"
4. Select SDK version to download and install

For more information use the [Appcelerator guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start)